# How do I handle with JPA annotation @ManytoMany

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, google-cloud-firestore, java-11

I'm doing a food truck API, just to learn spring-boot. While doing, came across on question about how the annotations @Manytomany works.

Because this project is only for learning I want to use the Google CLoud Firestore, I know that a NoSql database for this propose is definitely not the best option. So my database is new and empty how would I insert something if in both models refers it other

Ingredient Model:

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ingredientLunch", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lunch"), inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient"))
    private List<Lunch> lunch = new ArrayList<>();
```

Lunch Model:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "lunch")
    private List<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<>();
```

How its work? Also, I don't know anything about the Google Cloud Firestore with spring-boot what else I need to do the integration. And one more question, JPA is used outside at the industry? Can I use the Google Cloud Firestore with JPA? Maybe I'm a bit confused with what is JPA.

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a JPA implementation for Google Cloud Firestore. Your two best options are:

1. Instead of JPA switch to something similar for example https://catatumbo.io/
2. Use a rational database like Google Cloud Spanner, for which there are JPA implementations.

For an easy to follow discussion how `@ManyToMany` works in JPA, this Wikibook is a great resource: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany